# What is the word (____light) for shutting down a program or API at its end of life?

Tags: terminology

This has been driving me crazy for weeks. What's the word for when a program or API is being shut down?

> The servers are being twilighted.
>
> The API is being moonlighted.

I know that neither of these are it, but they're all I can think of when I'm trying to remember this word.

To prove that I thoroughly did try finding this on my own, and that every time I ran a Google search I failed to find it, here's the searches:

- [word for end of life](https://www.google.com/search?q=word%20for%20end%20of%20life&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
- [light word for shutting down program](https://www.google.com/search?q=light+word+for+shutting+down+project&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
- [word for ending software support](https://www.google.com/search?q=word%20for%20ending%20software%20support%20moonlighting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=word%20for%20ending%20software%20support)
- [word for ending software support moonlighting](https://www.google.com/search?q=word%20for%20ending%20software%20support%20moonlighting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
- [synonyms for deprecating](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20be%20moonlighted&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=synonyms%20for%20deprecating)
- [to be moonlighted](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20be%20moonlighted&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
- [moonlighted](https://www.google.com/search?q=moonlighted&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Also, the terminology is [not on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product)) for end-of-life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably thinking about [sunsetting](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/sunsetting) a product/service.

Comment: This is probably an instance of my neurodegenerative disorder swapping the meanings of words in my head, so instead of sun + setting I got moon + lighting. Thanks.